# "Error 502 - Bad gateway" using Screaming Frog on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to analyze [my WordPress website](https://atahualpa.com/) with [Screaming Frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/). However, I am getting an *"error 502 bad gateway"*. My site is working correctly. The problem is only with this tool.

I have already tried cleaning the cache and re-installing the program, but nothing works. Has someone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Are you running site in nginix server

Answer (score 0):

Your server might be blocking your request.

Are you able to change the user-agent to something else through Screaming Frog to retest this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file inside the root directory of your site. Are you using a site builder?

```
<ifmodule mod_substitute.c>
    SubstituteMaxLineLength 25M
</ifmodule>
```